# Write a function using a parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

Write a function called print_stars that takes a number as a parameter and outputs that many stars. You should output 1 star per line.

I have tried

```
def print_stars():
   num = (input("Input Number of stars")
   for i in range (0, num):
       print("*")

print_stars()
```

but I get an invalid syntax message.

Comment: `num = int(input("Input Number of stars"))` You almost had it buddy.

Comment: "threw·SyntaxError:
> ValueError:·invalid·literal·for·int()·with·base·10:·''  is the new error message.

Comment: Input an integer.... :/

Comment: `print("*" * num)` ;)

Comment: That is not a *function that takes a number as a parameter*. That's a *function that asks for input*. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is caused by a stray opening bracket:

```
num = (input("Input Number of stars")
------^------------------------------
```

You probably intended to convert the user input into an integer?

```
num = int(input("Input Number of stars"))
```

However, your task is to accept the number as a *parameter* to the function, so the next thing that you need to look at is to alter the function to accept a parameter. Remove the `input()` from the function and pass the count into the function when called:

```
def print_stars(n):
   for i in range(n):
       print("*")

print_stars(int(input('How many stars? ')))
```